# C# data bound ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, listbox

I have the following two [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) tables:

Employee table:

```
EmployeeID  
Name
```

etc.

Project table:

```
ProjectID  
EmployeeID  
ProjectDescription
```

Each Employee can manage zero or more projects.

I know how to use the `DataSet` Designer to add the Employee table as details (multiple bound controls) on `Form1` (**Windows Form Application**):

Dragging the Company database's Employee table (as details) to form creates the following components:

• CompanyDataSet
• employeeBindingSource
• employeeTableAdapter
• tableAdapterManager
• employeeBindingNavigator

1. How do you add a ListBox to Form1 that displays the ProjectDescription of all the projects the currently displayed Employee manages?  What ListBox properties need to be set?

   I believe I will need the following query:

   ```
   SELECT Project.ProjectDescription  
   FROM  Project RIGHT JOIN Employee ON Project.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID  
   WHERE EmployeeID = ?
   ```

   Parameter would be the employeeIDtextbox.Text
2. Project records will be created programmatically (OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand) from Form2.  What statement is required to update Form1 when it is displayed?

I have searched the web and read pages and pages of Microsoft documentation and have hit a wall...

Comment: @Aron - Winform.  Also edited query...

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get the ProjectDescriptions into the ListBox, you could simply iterate through the recordset returned by the query and add each entry to the listbox

```
foreach (DataRow r in foo)
{
    projectlistbox.Items.Add(r["ProjectDescription"]);
}
```

it's inelegant but it works. I can't promise that code does exactly though, I don't have a C# IDE to test it against with me. It should point you in the right direction though.

To update `Form1` after data has been entered from `Form2`, put code into `Form1.Activated` that checks for the updated data and changes objects on `Form1` appropriately.

Comment: @ tjennings - I want to do add items to the ListBox by changing it's DESIGN TIME properties - not programmatically.  What checks and objects?  I thought calling the Fill for the tableAdapters would do it, but that didn't work.